# Role of a domain registrar

Tags: domains, blogger, customer-service, ping, http-code-503

Few months back I bought a domain name and started using it through custom domain feature of Google Blogger. Since then my site was unavailable several times with different error forms:

1. A 'Not Found' text on the home page
2. No browser could not connect to the site

Now since a week the site is totally inaccessible. It never loads. I tried using services like [justping](http://www.just-ping.com) and [Whydown](http://whydown.com/). The former one reports 100% packet loss from all server locations while the latter reports a 503 error.

I am unable to understand whether the problem is from the domain registrar's side or Blogger's side. Last time when I contacted domain registrar over 'Site not found' issue they affirmed that it would be Blogger's problem. I find it hard to believe that problem occurs from Google end. So this time before contacting Domain registrar's customer support I want to arm myself with technical details on what is causing the problem. If someone could guide me in debugging my issue it would greatly benefit me.

For your information the website with the above problem - http://www.staygeo.com

Comment: the site is working to me. It could be that your router cached the DNS request. Unplug it, leave it a few sec and plug it back - if this is the problem should then work.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. The issue was with name server entries in the control panel for the domain. Domain registrar helped me solve it after they saw my tweet complaining about downtime. I am accepting the below answer as it can also help in several cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also able to reach it just fine. To test you can go through Google Translate and see if the domain is up. It's most likely your DNS cache, in windows you can run `ipconfig /flushdns` I would also try viewing the site in a private browser session which has no cache or history. Incognito in Chrome etc.